# Limit Disk Usage of WSL2

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, speed, resource-usage

As the title already states, I want to limit the disk usage of the Linux subsystem. I'm trying to build huge projects on the WSL while using Windows normally...

I already limited the RAM and CPU usage using the `.wslconfig` file, but I don't know how I can limit the disk usage without changing my Windows installation. I already found this thread about [limiting disk usage per application](https://superuser.com/questions/462541/how-to-limit-disk-usage-write-i-o-by-application-not-space-usage), but this won't work here, because the WSL accesses the file system using the Windows system, meaning the high disk usage is registered as "System". Limiting that would slow down my whole Windows environment.

So how can I limit the disk usage of WSL *without* affecting any other programs? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I was having Task Manager 100% disk utilization for "System", similar to you. I fixed the problem by setting swap=8GB in the .wslconfig, in addition to what you tried, with memory=4GB and processors=2. I don't know if that will help limit the disk usage in your case, but it reduced mine from 100% to 3%.

Answer (score -2):

This is probably not ideal and hopefully not the best solution, but you could create a VM using built-in Hyper-V (or whatever VM software you prefer) with the limits you prefer. That way, it is limited by the VM disk settings. I'll look around for other solutions when I get home and maybe we can find something.